# Send an email after 5 minutes by comparing 2 datetimes using PHP and FuelPHP framework

Tags: php, fuelphp

I am using MVC framework called FuelPhp I am aware this is an old framework but this is what the application runs on.

Trying to send an email comparing two datetimes, so if the website is down which is recorded in `$down_time`and five minutes have passed which is recorded in the `$last_checked_time` then an email should send. The problem I am having is the code seems to stop at this line `$difference = $last_checked_time->diff($down_time);` and is never hitting the if statement. Basically all I want to do is to check if the `$last_checked_time` is greater than the `$down_time` by 5 minutes. There are no errors been logged so I'm unsure what the problem is, I would really appreciate the help thank you.

```
                    $down_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $website->down_at);
                    $last_checked_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $website->last_checked);

                    $difference = $last_checked_time->diff($down_time);

                    if ($difference->format("a") > 0 || $difference->format("h") > 0 || $difference->format("m") >= 5) {

                        Cli::write("Emailing: " . $website->url . " is offline");

                        $notify_emails = array();

                        foreach ($services as $service)
                        {
                            $service_id = $service->service_id;
                            if (in_array($service_id, $dept_emails))
                            {
                                $notify_emails[] = $dept_emails[$service_id];
                            }
                        }

                        $message = "Hi," . $website->url . " has been down since " . $website->down_at . ".";
                        $email = Model_Mail::send_email($dept_emails, "" . $website->url . " is down", $message);

                        $result = DB::update('clients_websites')
                            ->set(array(
                                'down_email_sent' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                            ))
                            ->where('id', '=', $website->id)
                            ->execute();
                    }
```

Comment: For you sanity's sake, I would check the return value of `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to make sure it isn't false which happens if that fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `format` you need to use a `%` symbol in front of the [format string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php):

```php
if ($difference->format("%a") > 0 || $difference->format("%h") > 0 || $difference->format("%m") >= 5) {
```

Also, `%m` is months. If you want minutes you should use `%i`.

*edit*

Also again, the `DateInterval` class can be annoying because you have to check many properties, it might be easier to just deal with seconds:

```php
$diff_in_seconds = $last_checked_time->getTimestamp() - $down_time->getTimestamp();
if($diff_in_seconds >= 300){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Just done var_dump for both the down time and last checked time variables and are returning the correct dates, when I tried output  ```$difference``` variable doesn't seem to return a value. For the second solution how would put that into an if statement since it doesn't support the format method?

Comment: I added an `if` statement showing that, 300 is obviously 60 seconds times 5 minutes

Comment: Thanks Chris it's working now really appreciate your help.